# Is adding registry failed?

Tags: c

I tried to add a registry called hello.
When run, it also returns 0 and prints "success".

But when I go to the Registry Editor along the path, hello doesn't look like the picture.

What is the problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvF7H.png)

```
if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regSubKeyPath, 0, NULL,
        REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegSetValueEx(hKey, valueName, 0, REG_EXPAND_SZ, (BYTE*)path, wcslen(path));
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        printf("success");
    }
    else {
        printf("fail");
    }
```

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE requires elevation. Also check the return value of RegSetValueEx

Comment: It returns 0...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you provided `wcslen`, you are trying to write a Unicode string to the registry.

1. The size of the string your are passing to `RegSetValueEx` is incorrect, as `wcslen` returns the number of characters, but the function expect the length in bytes.
2. Call for a UNICODE version of the function RegSetValueExW

   ```
   RegSetValueEx(hKey, valueName, 0, REG_EXPAND_SZ, (BYTE*)path, (wcslen(path)+1) + sizeof(wchar_t))
   ```

BTW:
It's always a good practice to check the return value of the function and call for [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror)() to get an extended information regarding the error.